# Trying to get Stenohide to work

Tags: dll, exe

Just downloaded the stenohide zip file, and copied the given .dll files onto windows\system32
However when I try to run stenohide.exe, it does not work at all. 
Could you please help, thanks.

Error message- I put the exe on my desktop and tried to run it, and error message said:

The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling...

I have cygwin1 in my system32 directory.

Comment: Please add an error message if any (or at least describe what "doesn't work" means).

Comment: Do not copy dlls to system32 manually. You can start your exe from cygwin or add cygwin dll path to enviroment PATH.

Comment: thanks got it to work using cmd terminal. But you were right, manually moving the dlls were pointless.